# how to reshape my data frame in R (transpose, select, remove row)?

Tags: r

Here is data frame(ttt) I have:

```
 .id     dn     mavg    up      pctB
AA.1    18.8    21.1    23.4    0.8 
AA.2    18.7    21.1    23.5    0.8 
AA.3    18.7    21.2    23.7    0.8 
AAN.1   23.1    24.6    26.1    0.5 
AAN.2   23.1    24.6    26.0    0.4 
AAN.3   23.1    24.5    26.0    0.5 
AAP.1   145.5   179.2   212.9   0.3 
AAP.2   144.2   177.4   210.7   0.3 
AAP.3   143.4   175.6   207.7   0.3
```

The shape that I want to have is following:

```
    pctB.1  pctB.2  pctB.3
AA  0.8     0.8     0.8 
AAN 0.5     0.4     0.5 
AAP 0.3     0.3     0.3
```

Only column that I need is pctB. I tried by writing:

```
ttt <- ttt %>% select(1,5)
ttt <- do.call(cbind, split(ttt, ttt$`.id`))
ttt <- t(ttt)
```

it gives a result that I don't want. What should I do?

```
<error/rlang_error>
`n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs.
Backtrace:
  1. plyr::mutate(., .id = sub("\\..*", "", .id))
  1. dplyr::group_by(., .id)
  8. plyr::mutate(., col = paste0("pctB.", row_number()))
  9. [ base::eval(...) ] with 1 more call
 12. dplyr::row_number()
 13. dplyr::n()
 14. dplyr:::peek_mask("n()")
 15. dplyr:::context_peek("mask", fun)
 16. context_peek_bare(name) %||% abort(glue("`{fun}` must only be used inside {location}."))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove additional characters from it, create a unique id column and get the data in wide format selecting only the interested columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)

ttt %>%
  mutate(.id = sub('\\..*', '', .id)) %>%
  group_by(.id) %>%
  mutate(col = paste0('pctB.', row_number())) %>%
  select(-(dn:up)) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = col, values_from = pctB)

#  .id   pctB.1 pctB.2 pctB.3
#  <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 AA       0.8    0.8    0.8
#2 AAN      0.5    0.4    0.5
#3 AAP      0.3    0.3    0.3
```

**data**

```
ttt <- structure(list(.id = c("AA.1", "AA.2", "AA.3", "AAN.1", "AAN.2", 
"AAN.3", "AAP.1", "AAP.2", "AAP.3"), dn = c(18.8, 18.7, 18.7, 
23.1, 23.1, 23.1, 145.5, 144.2, 143.4), mavg = c(21.1, 21.1, 
21.2, 24.6, 24.6, 24.5, 179.2, 177.4, 175.6), up = c(23.4, 23.5, 
23.7, 26.1, 26, 26, 212.9, 210.7, 207.7), pctB = c(0.8, 0.8, 
0.8, 0.5, 0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3)),class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Comment: I'm so sorry. I just noticed that first column has a name, ".id". Should I change something in your codes ?

Comment: I got an error, "`n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs." It looks it worked in your R, right?

Comment: Yes it works for me. Does it work with the data in my post? If yes, then you may need to provide your data or part of data using `dput` similarly.

Comment: It does not work with the data in your post. I updated error information I got. I also restarted R.

Comment: That's strange because it works fine for me. Use `dplyr::mutate` instead of just `mutate` and try.

Comment: Could you do me a favor? I found that pctB calculated from R is wrong, so I should manually calculate pctB. To do that, I just want to keep every data, all of the four columns, "dn", "mavg", "up" and "pctB". Could you modify the codes you wrote above?

Comment: You can remove the `select` line from the answer to keep all the columns but then the values are not unique there so number of rows would remain the same.

Comment: I think I should repost my question. Thank you Ronak!!

Answer (score 0):

Split `.id` into two separate columns (eg. `"AA.1"` -> `"AA", "1"`), then pivot it by these two columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

ttt %>%
  mutate(.id.1 = str_split(.id, "\\.") %>% map(~ .[[1]]) %>% unlist,
         .id.2 = str_split(.id, "\\.") %>% map(~ paste0("pctB.", .[[2]])) %>% unlist) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = .id.1,
              names_from = .id.2,
              values_from = pctB) %>%
  column_to_rownames(".id.1")
```